# DataStax OpsCenter provisioning failed: Could not find a matching version for package dse-libpig

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I'm using Ops center v5.2.4 to install DataStax Enterprise v4.8.1 in a local cluster and following guide:

[http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/online_help/opscCreateClusterLocal.html][1],

but it keeps failing due to error(/var/log/datastar-agent/agent.log):

```
  INFO [Thread-22] 2016-04-29 09:19:18,777 Checking for already installed packages
  INFO [Thread-22] 2016-04-29 09:19:18,778 Running apt-get install dry-run
  INFO [Thread-22] 2016-04-29 09:19:19,347 Running sudo command.
 ERROR [Thread-22] 2016-04-29 09:19:19,381 Installation failed:  #<ExceptionInfo clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: throw+: {:type :installation-error, :message "Could not find a matching versi$
 clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: throw+: {:type :installation-error, :message "Could not find a matching version for package dse-libpig"}
              deb.clj:138 opsagent.installation.deb/make-versioned-package
            core.clj:2487 clojure.core/map[fn]
          LazySeq.java:42 clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval
          LazySeq.java:67 clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq
              RT.java:484 clojure.lang.RT.seq
             core.clj:133 clojure.core/seq
             core.clj:687 clojure.core/concat[fn]
          LazySeq.java:42 clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval
          LazySeq.java:60 clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq
              RT.java:484 clojure.lang.RT.seq
             core.clj:133 clojure.core/seq
            core.clj:2605 clojure.core/drop-while[fn]
            core.clj:2609 clojure.core/drop-while[fn]
          LazySeq.java:42 clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval
          LazySeq.java:60 clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq
              RT.java:484 clojure.lang.RT.seq
             core.clj:133 clojure.core/seq
             core.clj:617 clojure.core/apply
             shell.clj:50 clojure.java.shell/parse-args
            shell.clj:112 clojure.java.shell/sh
          RestFn.java:137 clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo
             core.clj:617 clojure.core/apply
             proc.clj:158 opsagent.proc/sudo
          RestFn.java:423 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
              deb.clj:157 opsagent.installation.deb/dry-run
             Var.java:419 clojure.lang.Var.invoke
             AFn.java:163 clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper
             Var.java:532 clojure.lang.Var.applyTo
             core.clj:617 clojure.core/apply
           install.clj:20 opsagent.installation.install/package-specific
          RestFn.java:439 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
           install.clj:76 opsagent.installation.install/run-installation[fn]
              AFn.java:24 clojure.lang.AFn.run
          Thread.java:745 java.lang.Thread.run
```

I'm sure the credential is right and ssh is enabled.
Can anyone help to get me out?

Comment: What OS are you installing on?

Comment: Is this Ubuntu 12, 14, 16? Debian?

Comment: Resolved the problem by removing a trailing '@' in my datastax account password. Thanks!

Comment: Sweet... glad you where able to resolve this.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason whatever operation that agents do don't tolerate `@` character (at least at the end of the password), botching some operations. If you have password with `@` - change it to something without it.